# Matrix to Tuple conversion for Python 2.7-OpenCV-cv2resize function that results to TypeError

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, matrix, tuples

Is there any way to convert this matrix to tuple? Because I'm having error that the im matrix result is not in tuple?

This is the line of code I used to convert the matrix to tuple but it's wrong. Just a newbie here in Python language.

```
im = tuple(im)
im = cv2.resize(im, scaling)
```

returns this error in the IDLE:

```
 [[ 0.14417706  0.18959087  0.2234258  ...,  0.16840368  0.15120561 0.11965712]
[ 0.19098209  0.25031347  0.29384765 ...,  0.21637971  0.19531406  0.1554829 ]
[ 0.22742296  0.29720085  0.34758183 ...,  0.24855714  0.22531588 0.1804396 ]]
im = cv2.resize(im2, scaling)
TypeError: src is not a numerical tuple
```

[**TypeError: src is not a numerical tuple** - python IDLE screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIldJ.png)

Comment: Please post error messages as plain text in the question and show your Python code. How is `im` obtained before these two lines of code?

Comment: I just updated it, sorry it was late.

Comment: def canny(im=None, sigma=None, scaling=None, vert=None, horz=None):
    
    xscaling = vert
    yscaling = horz

    hsize = (6 * sigma + 1), (6 * sigma + 1)# The filter size.

    gaussian = gauss2D(hsize, sigma)
    im = filter2(gaussian, im)# Smoothed image.

this is how     im is obtained